# Split string and take part and put this in different variable

Tags: c#

Hello I have a variable
myvar: "123,2344,567,3334"
I need to extract the value after second comma and put this on another varivle that will be used to write in file:
my code:

```
myvar: "123,2344,567,3334"
var items = myvar.Split( ',');
var val=items[3]
// Add on file

string row = Convert.ToString(val) + ";" + "Amount";
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter(fileName, true);
 file2.WriteLine(row);
 file2.Close();
```

However I got the error : Can not deserialize from string_val.

Is there anything wronf with my code?

I need to extract the value after second comma and put this on another variable.

Comment: that error message seems to have nothing to do with this code. Looks like a try catch in the caller of this code. Can we see it please

Comment: I would add an additional check to make sure you have at least 3 elements in your resulting array after calling split, before attempting to hit that index number: `if (items.Length >=3) { ... }`.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with a deserialization problem with `string_val` when your code contains neither `string_val` nor any code that deserializes anything?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var myvar = "123,2344,567,3334";
var items = myvar.Split(',');
var val=items[2]; // 0-based indexing so 2 is the 3rd element.


File.AppendAllText("file.txt", contents: val);
```

---

Version for multiple rows:

```
var rows = new [] {"a,aa,111,aaaa",
                   "b,bb,222,bbbb"};

var o = new List<string>();
foreach(var row in rows)
{
    var items = row.Split(',');
    o.Add(items[2]); // 0-based indexing so 2 is the 3rd element.
}

File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", contents: o); // Or File.AppendAllLines()

// file.txt will contian: 
// 111
// 222
```

After this file.txt will contain `567`.

Comment: Is there any way to use File.AppendAllText to insert many rows?
I will have many variables like myvar and I want to extract always the third position and insert in file. Using you code I will have this 565, 454, 666 insted of
564 ,
454,
666
by row

Comment: There are several ways to add multiple lines. I updated the answer with one possible version...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myvar = "123,2344,567,3334";
var items = myvar.Split(',');
var val = items[2];

//Write to the file
string row = Convert.ToString(val) + ";" + "Amount";
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("yourfilename", true);
file2.WriteLine(row);
file2.Close();
```

Comment: It seems not working the MessageBox is shown underlined in red